# cannot pass object variable to jade layout in express

Tags: express, pug

Below is NOT work with Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

layout.jade

```
div #{person.name}
block content
```

page.jade

```
extends ../_layout
block content
div #{person.name}
```

server render

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  var data= {name: "Tom"}
  res.render('page',{person: data})
})
```

Below will WORK

layout.jade

```
div #{person}
block content
```

page.jade

```
extends ../_layout
block content
div #{person}
```

server render

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){

  res.render('page',{person: "data"})
})
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: and how the html result looks like with the last example which is _working_?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
div=person.name
```

or

```
div Some text #{person.name}
```

or try using *locals*

```
res.locals.person=data
res.render('page')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the data in a array so that the position is specified from where the key is to be retrieved. Something like this should work

layout.jade

```
div #{person[0].name}
block content
```

page.jade

```
extends ../_layout
block content
div #{person[0].name}
```

server render

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
var data=[] 
data.push({name: "Tom"})
res.render('page',data)
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work with error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: `person.name` is a object notation not array notation

Comment: The data that you are trying to pass is

Comment: Try adding " to your keys as person should be "person". This might solve your problem as there are some cases where you have to stringify the json to pass it on.